# UIButton inside view controller not responding to any action

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I'm creating a view controller with a button and picker view as follows, the problem is that the button doesn't respond to any action i.e. `dismissButtonPushed` not called

```
    UIViewController* x=[[UIViewController alloc]init];
    UIButton* btn=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(50,80,250,50);
    [btn setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissButtonPushed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn setEnabled:true];
    [btn setTitle:@"Dismiss" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [x.view setBounds:CGRectMake(0,-250, 350,350)];
    [x.view addSubview:btn];
    [x.view addSubview:self.productfamilyPikerview];
    x.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
    [self.searchButton setHidden:true];
    [self presentViewController:x animated:YES completion:nil];
```

also here's `dismissButtonPushed` method:

```
-(void)dismissButtonPushed:(id)sender{

}
```

Comment: Is the button even responding to your touches? Did you cover it with something transparent?

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
[btn addTarget:x action:@selector(dismissButtonPushed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

to

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissButtonPushed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: if its helped, please mark it as accepted answer for future users who search for the same. Thanks.

Comment: The OP would have been experiencing a crash if this was the (only) problem.

Comment: what does OP stands for?

Comment: Original Poster (The user who asked the question, gender neutral). http://netforbeginners.about.com/od/internetlanguage/f/What-Is-OP.htm